# Is there a way to delete and return value of subquery

Tags: postgresql, subquery, common-table-expression

I want to be able to return the value of subquery and delete certain records. Specifically I want delete from the following table only if none of the records have `used = True` and also return the number of records that are used.

```
csv_files
----------|-------
filename  | used  | somevalue |
-------------------------------
test.csv  | t     | 67
-------------------------------
test.csv  | f     | 92
-------------------------------
test.csv  | f     | 92
-------------------------------
```

I came with the following:

```
with used_count as (
   select count(used) 
   from csv_files 
   where filename ='test.csv' 
     and used = 't'
), delete as (
   delete from csv_files 
   where filename = 'test.csv' 
    and (select count from used_count) = 0
) 
select count 
from used_count;
```

```
count
-------
  1     
(1 row)
```

Is there a simpler way to do this in Postgres?

Comment: I don't think so. I believe your way to do it is good. If it is too slow, an index might help.